# Schrodinger equation $iψ'(t) = H(t)ψ(t),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, ψ(t_0) = ψ_0,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

(Quantum Mechanics). A quantum mechanical system which
can only attain finitely many states is described by a complex-valued vector
$ψ(t) ∈ \mathbb{C}^n$. The square of the absolute values of the components $|ψ_j(t)|^2$ is
interpreted as the probability of finding the system in the $j’th$ state at time
$t$. Since there are only $n$ possible states, these probabilities must add up to one, that is, $ψ(t)$ must be normalized, $|ψ(t)| = 1$. The time evolution of the
system is governed by the **Schrodinger equation**

$iψ'(t) = H(t)ψ(t),\quad ψ(t_0) = ψ_0,$

where $H(t)$, is a self-adjoint matrix, that is, $H(t)^∗ = H(t)$. (Here $A^∗$ is the
adjoint (complex conjugate of the transposed) matrix.) The matrix $H(t)$ is
called the Hamiltonian and describes the interaction. Show that the solution
is given by

$ψ(t) = U(t, t_0)ψ_0, \quad U(t_0, t_0) = \mathbb{I},$

where $U(t, t_0)$ is unitary, that is, $U(t, t_0)^{−1} = U(t, t_0)^∗$ .

(Hint: Given $A(t)$ and B(t) matrices, holds: $\dfrac{d(A(t).B(t))}{dt}=A'(t)B(t)+A(t)B'(t)$ and $\dfrac{d(A(t)^{-1})}{dt}=-A(t)^{-1}A'(t)A(t)^{-1}$).

Conclude that $ψ(t)$ remains normalized for all $t$ if $ψ_0$ is.

Each observable (quantity you can measure) corresponds to a self-adjoint
matrix, say $L_0$. The expectation value for a measurement of $L_0$ if the system
is in the state $ψ(t)$ is given by

$\langle ψ(t), L_0ψ(t) \rangle,$

where $ \langle ϕ, ψ \rangle = ϕ^∗ · ψ$ is the scalar product in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Show that

$\dfrac{d\langle ψ(t), L_0ψ(t) \rangle}{dt}= i \langle ψ(t), [H(t), L_0]ψ(t) \rangle$

where $[H, L] = HL − LH$ is the commutator.

In fact I do not know how to start solving this problem. Can someone help me? 
The biggest problem is that I do not know anything about the behavior of this array $H(t)$.

Comment: The intuition is that you solve with the exponential of the Hamiltonian operator:

$ \psi (t) =  exp(-i H(t)) \psi (0) $. Maybe this helps to give some insights. Look for Lie Groups if your are completely lost.

What can you say about the generator of an unitary Lie group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\psi(t) = U(t, t_0) \psi(t_0)$ for some matrix $U$ (which you don't know is unitary just yet). Plug this into Schrodinger's equation

$$
i\frac{{\rm d} U(t,t_0)}{{\rm d}t} = H(t) U(t, t_0) \tag{1}
$$

Take the adjoint ($A^\dagger$ means take the transpose of $A$ and then complex conjugate each element)

$$
-i\frac{{\rm d} U^\dagger(t,t_0)}{{\rm d}t} = U(t, t_0)^\dagger H(t) \tag{2}
$$

Since I used the fact that $H^{\dagger}(t) = H(t)$. Now consider

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d} }{{\rm d}t}\left(U^\dagger(t,t_0)U(t,t_0)\right) &=& U^\dagger(t,t_0) \frac{{\rm d} U(t,t_0)}{{\rm d}t} + \frac{{\rm d} U^\dagger(t,t_0)}{{\rm d}t}U(t,t_0) \\
&\stackrel{(1),(2)}=& -iU^{\dagger}(t,t_0)H(t) U(t,t_0)+iU^{\dagger}(t,t_0)H(t) U(t,t_0) \\
&=& 0 \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

That means that $U^\dagger(t,t_0) U(t,t_0)$ is constant at all times, but you have the initial condition $U^\dagger(t_0,t_0) U(t_0,t_0) = 1$, which implies that

$$
U^\dagger(t,t_0) U(t,t_0) = 1 \tag{4}
$$

This shows that $U(t,t_0)$ is unitary.

For the second part, consider the norm of the vector $\psi(t)$

\begin{eqnarray}
|\psi(t)|^2 &=& \psi(t)^\dagger\psi(t) = \left(U(t,t_0) \psi_0\right)^\dagger \left(U(t,t_0) \psi_0\right) \\
&=&\psi(t_0)^\dagger \left(U(t,t_0)^\dagger U(t,t_0) \right) \psi(t_0) \\
&\stackrel{(4)}{=}&  \psi(t_0)^\dagger 1 \psi(t_0)\\
&=& \psi(t_0)^\dagger \psi(t_0) \\
&=& |\psi(t_0)|^2 \tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}

The norm is preserved under unitary evolution